# Difference between dashDB for Analytics and dashDB for Transactions?

Tags: dashdb

DashDB has plans that are listed as "transactional" or "for transactions". Under the hood, what is the difference between dashDB for Analytics and dashDB for Transactions? Are there limitations to either one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**dashDB for Analytics:** Tuned for analytics (large, complex queries, sometimes called OLAP). In particular, tables are column-organized by default. (If you run a `CREATE TABLE` statement, by default it is `ORGANIZE BY COLUMN`.)

- Limitation: Some things, like CLOB data types, do not work with column-organized tables. If you need a regular row-organized table in dashDB for Analytics, you need to specify it: `CREATE TABLE.. ORGANIZE BY ROW`.

**dashDB for Transactions:** Also referred to as "transactional plans" or "dashDB TX" is tuned for transactions (OLTP) or typical web workloads. Tables are organized by row (the typical SQL default).

In sum, if you're doing heavy analysis work, generating big reports, or R scripting, then choose dashDB for Analytics. For most general purpose workloads, dashDB for Transactions is a better fit.